# how to access all stack panel in DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

how to access all stack panel in DataGridTemplateColumn?

I'm using this code :

```
           <DataGrid HeadersVisibility="None"  Name="dgUser" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
 CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="" IsReadOnly="True">
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0"  Name="spGuns">
                                                    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="Count"/>
                                                    <TextBox Margin="0,0,5,0" MinWidth="50" Width="Auto" Name="txtCount" Text="{Binding Count}"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="NameEn"/>
                                                    <TextBox Margin="0,0,5,0" MinWidth="50" Width="Auto" Name="txtGunNameEn" Text="{Binding NameEn}"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
```

data in datagrid :

http://www.imagetoo.com/?v=untitlfif.png

how to access all stack panel in DataGridTemplateColumn?

Answer (score 0):

Change the property "Name" of your StackPanel in "x:Name" like this
`<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="spGuns">
  <TextBlock Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="Count"/>
  <TextBox Margin="0,0,5,0" MinWidth="50" Width="Auto" Name="txtCount" Text="{Binding Count}"/>
  <TextBlock Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="NameEn"/>
  <TextBox Margin="0,0,5,0" MinWidth="50" Width="Auto" Name="txtGunNameEn" Text="{Binding NameEn}"/>
</StackPanel>`
Your StackPanel will be programmatically available.

Comment: @user1799345 After some searches, it seems that the only way to have control programmaticaly on the elements of your data template is to create from behind side :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097349/changing-label-content-programmatically-from-within-a-datatemplate-used-in-a-dat
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f230804d-fc0f-4321-a61e-69a2c890b28d/

Answer (score 0):

Add this class to go through each row of dataDrid

```
  public IEnumerable<DataGridRow> GetDataGridRows(DataGrid grid)
    {
        var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
        if (null == itemsSource) yield return null;
        foreach (var item in itemsSource)
        {
            var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
            if (null != row) yield return row;
        }
    }
```

Then Your Problem is to find control solve

```
foreach (DataGridRow row in GetDataGridRows(dgUser))
        {
            if (row.IsEnabled)
            {
                try
                {
                    ContentPresenter cp = dgUser.Columns[i].GetCellContent(row) as ContentPresenter;
                    DataTemplate myDataTemplate = cp.ContentTemplate;
                    TextBox t = (TextBox)myDataTemplate.FindName("textBoxName", cp);
                    t.Text = //Do something 
                }
                catch (Exception)
                { }
            }
        }
```